# re finditer produces javascript with uncaught exception

Tags: javascript, python, transcrypt

I am trying to compile some simple Python code to Javascript using "transcrypt -e 6".  When I use finditer from Python's re module, the resultant Javascript code has an uncaught exception during runtime.

python:

```
import re

re_token = re.compile('\w+')

def tokenize(s):
    positions = []
    for m in re_token.finditer(s):
        positions.append(m.start(0))
    return positions

print(tokenize('select * from x'))
```

stack trace:

```
Uncaught Function {__class__: ƒ, __args__: Array(1), stack: "No stack trace available", __cause__: null}
(anonymous) @   x.js:2838
(anonymous) @   x.js:53
tokenize    @   x.js:3566
(anonymous) @   VM68:1
```

the top element on the stack:

```
get finditer () {return __get__ (this, function (self, string, pos, endpos) {
                            if (typeof endpos == 'undefined' || (endpos != null && endpos .hasOwnProperty ("__kwargtrans__"))) {;
                                var endpos = null;
                            };
                            var __except0__ = NotImplementedError ('No Iterator Support in es5');
                            __except0__.__cause__ = null;
                            throw __except0__;
                        });},
```

Answer (score 0):

The `re` module still lacks some functionality.
As you can see here

https://github.com/QQuick/Transcrypt/issues/443

someone volunteered to work on it.
Unfortunately no progress has been reported recently,
so probably this issue got stuck somewhere.

Since we had no report to the contrary,
we've assumed this still is under construction. If however the current situation continues we'll be on the look for someone
to take over this task.

Jacques